# C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'A<double>' to 'A<double>'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variable-assignment

This code throws a compilation error in Visual Studio 2017:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T a);
   ~A() {}
#if 0
    A(const A<T>&);
#else
    A(A<T>&);
#endif

    T t;
};

template<class T>
A<T>::A(T a) : t(a) {}

template <class T>
#if 0
A<T>::A(const A<T>& a) 
#else
A<T>::A(A<T>& a)
#endif
{
    t = a.t;
    std::cout << "In A copy constructor.\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    
    A<int> a1(11);
    A<double> a2(2.71);
#if 1
    A<double> a3 = A<double>(a2);  //gives C2440 when copy constructor argument is not const.
                                   //compiler message is: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'A<double>' to 'A<double>'
#else    
    A<double> a3{a2};              //works when copy constructor argument is not const.
#endif
        
    std::cout << a3.t << "\n";
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit.\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

The compilation fails with C2440:  `'initializing': cannot convert from 'A<double>' to 'A<double>'.`  When the first two `#if 0`s are changed to `#if 1`s (selecting the copy constructor with the const argument), the program compiles and runs.  Also if `#if 0` is selected for all the conditional compilations, the program compiles and runs.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694655/error-c2440-initializing-cannot-convert-from-ctable-to-ctable) has no answer to mine. According to cppreference.com, copy constructors with non-const arguments are possible:

> A copy constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter **is T&‍,** const T&‍, volatile T&‍, or const volatile T&‍, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values.

and the copy constructor with the non-const argument works anyway when I write

`A<double> a3{a2};`

So why does initializing with

`A<double> a3 = A<double>(a2);`

not work when the argument of the copy constructor is not const?

Comment: Because modifying a temporary isn't allowed, and that's what a non-const reference parameter means, "I'm going to modify the parameter."

Comment: To improve the question, please post the version which can be compiled unmodified to give the error  (as opposed to posting a correct version and describing modifications which give an error).   It is not really necessary to include the non-erroneous version either.

Comment: note - since C++17, `A<double> a3 = A<double>(a2);` is exactly equivalent to `A<double> a3{a2};`  , but presumably the compiler version you are using either doesn't support C++17 or was not set to that mode

Comment: I get the same result when I compile with C++17:  `A<double> a3{a2}` works, and `A<double> a3 = A<double>(a2)` doesn't compile when I select the copy constructor without the const argument.

Comment: Ah well spotted @M.M. I can confirm that, with both clang and gcc, this compiles without error when `-std=c++17` is set.

Comment: Plus, both ways generate literally the same assembly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, the MSVC error message is particularly lacking; if you run GCC over this you get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:42:20: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘A<double>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘A<double>’
   42 |     A<double> a3 = A<double>(a2);  //gives C2440 when copy constructor argument is not const.
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:28:15: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘A<T>::A(A<T>&) [with T = double]’
   28 | A<T>::A(A<T>& a)
      |         ~~~~~~^
make: *** [<builtin>: main] Error 1
```

If you strip away all the unrelated parts of your example, you are left with:

```
int main() {
  double &a = 2.71;
}
```

which still returns the same error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:2:13: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘double&’ to an rvalue of type ‘double’
    2 |   double &a = 2.71;
      |             ^~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: main] Error 1
```

To unpack this, we need to look at the different [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) in C++ and what restrictions there are on each:

- An `lvalue` is, broadly, something that has a name. In your original failing example, the `lvalue` is the `A<T> &a` parameter of the copy constructor, and in my stripped down example, it's `double &a`.
- An `rvalue` is a bit trickier, but it's effectively something without a name. Often it's referred to as a `temporary` (as @Eljay has done in their comment) because without a name, it has no lifetime, so it is destructed almost immediately (with a caveat as explained below). In your example, the `rvalue` is `A<double>(a2)`, and in mine it's `2.71`.

There are two parts of the linked cppreference page regarding `rvalue`s that are relevant here:

- Address of an rvalue cannot be taken by built-in address-of operator: `&int()`, `&i++`, `&42`, and `&std::move(x)` are invalid
- An rvalue may be used to initialize a const lvalue reference, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends

This first point is what causes the issue with the copy constructor without `const` being passed an `rvalue`; based on the language rules, the object being referred to is no longer valid inside the constructor.

The second point is what allows the copy constructor with `const` to operate when passed an `rvalue`; the lifetime is extended until the reference inside the constructor ends, which allows the constructor to copy out member variables etc.

##### Copy elision wrinkle

The two ways that you are initialising `a3` differ as the first:

```
A<double> a3{a2};
```

only calls the copy constructor once, with an `lvalue` (`a2`) whereas the second:

```
A<double> a3 = A<double>(a2);
```

calls the copy constructor twice, the first time with an `lvalue` (`a2`) as above, the second with an `rvalue` (the result of the first constructor invocation). However, the [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) optimisation will remove one of the invocations, which can be confusing at first glance, as it may not be apparent which of those two copy constructor invocations is causing the issue.

Comment: How can `A<double> a3 = A<double>(a2)` call the copy constructor twice?  Why not just once?

Comment: You have the first invocation at `A<double>(a2)`, and the second used in lieu of a custom assignment operator when assigning to `a3`. Note that, as mentioned, one is generally optimised away; even moreso with C++17 which pretty much guarantees copy elision, as part of the [temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) change.

Comment: If `A<double>(a2)` assigns an lvalue (a2) to an lvalue reference (`A<double>& a)`, and then the assignment assigns an lvalue reference (`A<double>& a)` to an lvalue (a3), then where is there room for your claim that I am assigning an rvalue to an lvalue reference?

Comment: Firstly, pre C++17, the result of `A<double>(a2)` is an rvalue. Secondly, the compiler will look for a [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) or [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) implementation then, failing that, will fall back to the copy constructor which has been implemented. Hence, the end result is the attempted binding of the rvalue (`A<double>(a2)`) to a non-const lvalue reference (`A<T> &a`).